# Realtime DB events don't work when subscribed to from Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04
- Firebase SDK version: 4.8.0
- Library version 5.5.1
- Node version: 7.8.0
- Firebase Product: database

Hey! Yesterday my server with Admin SDK stopped working. After a little investigation it turns out that events don't fire anymore. For example, the following code neither fails or succeedes (the process is running forever). It is run on a local dev server:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const config = require('./config')
const signature = require('./signature.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(signature),
  databaseURL: config.databaseURL
})
admin.database()
admin.database().ref('/config').once('value')
  .then(snapshot => console.log(snapshot.val()))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

module.exports = {}
```

Database events are working when I subscribe to them as a client. Also database is accesible from web console. I've tried generating a new private key (credentials), but it doesn't help. What am I missing? Is there a way to take a closer look at what's going on? Maybe enabling debug mode somehow?

Comment: Did you change the version of your Admin SDK by any chance? Even that shouldn't matter of course, but it would give a place to start. Aside from that, the first thing to try would indeed to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database#.enableLogging) and see if there's any hint whether/why it loses its connection.

Comment: Admin SDK verision is 4.8.0 (I don't even know how to change it). The NPM library is unchanged. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the reason is `your server time is not properly synced`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what to do with that last bit. When you enable logging, I expect that the client will generate quite some additional logging about its connection status.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I'm sorry for confusing you. There was indeed a bunch of other data in the logs, I just copied the relevant part. The problem was that the time on my machine was out of sync. After synchronising it the database is working again. Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear Eugene. I've never seen that message before, but great to know that it helped you fix he problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling loggin I was able to figure out what's wrong.

```
// Enable logging
admin.database.enableLogging(true)
```

The problem was that the time on my machine was out of sync. After synchronising it the database is working again.